# Pytorch LongTensor of large integer gives float float value

Tags: python, pytorch

```
x = torch.LongTensor([108500])
print (x)
```

gives

```py
1.0850e+05
[torch.LongTensor of size 1]
```

Why is it so? Can't we have LongTensor of large integer?
How can I convert the value of x to be integer so that I can get the embedding of x.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html), `torch.LongTensor` uses the data type `'64-bit integer (signed)'`.

So what you are seeing in your output is actually an integer, it's only the exponential notation.

Comment: If you want to access the Python variable which will return a normal integer use `x.item()` (since pytorch 0.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an integer. 1.0850e+05 is 1.0850* 10^5, that is, 108500.